# Know any great online services to receive inbound email?

Tags: email, inbound

Our web app will receive a very high amount of inbound email.  Amazon SES does not handle inbound email at this time, but I know that Cloudmailin and Sendgrid do.  Cloudmailin is in beta and its custom domain feature is currently experimental, but perhaps it will be safe enough soon enough!  Do you know of any other great online mail services with this feature that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, we (CloudMailin) actually lifted the experimental status of custom domains and attachments today as the features have been pretty stable for several months now and we did an upgrade to begin to get things ready for the paid plans. If you have any specific questions feel free to contact us directly.

Answer (score 0):

check out https://postmarkapp.com/inbound [I am not affiliated to them in any way]. Have used their services for one of my projects and they are really good.